# NullPointerException (Help!)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have been using the bookClasses set of classes to manipulate images and I am getting a NullPointerException error when trying to remove red eye in an image. Here is the code:

First the `removeRedEye` method which is inside the Picture.Java class:

```
 public void removeRedEye(int startX, int startY, int endX, int endY, Color newColor){

    Pixel pixel = null;

    for (int x = startX; x < endX; x++){
        for (int y = startY; y < endY; y++){
            if (pixel.colorDistance(Color.RED) < 167){
                        pixel.setColor(newColor);
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

and the Test Class:

```
public class TestRemoveRedEye{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String fileName = FileChooser.getMediaPath("//jenny-red.jpg");

        Picture jennyPicture = new Picture(fileName);

        jennyPicture.removeRedEye(109,91,202,107,java.awt.Color.BLACK); 

        jennyPicture.explore();

    }
}
```

If anyone could suggest why my program isn't working it would be greatly appreciated.

These lines are singled out in the error:
`if (pixel.colorDistance(Color.RED) < 167){` from the removeRedEye method

`jennyPicture.removeRedEye(109,91,202,107,java.awt.Color.BLACK);`  from the test class

Answer (score 2):

**pixel** is **null** you need to initialize it before you invoke methods on its reference.

```
Pixel pixel = null;// neew to initialize this.
pixel = new Pixel(); // somethin like this 
for (int x = startX; x < endX; x++){
    for (int y = startY; y < endY; y++){
        if (pixel.colorDistance(Color.RED) < 167){
```

Answer (score 1):

You assign null to `pixel` and you call a method on it just after. Hence the NPE.

```
Pixel pixel = null;
for (int x = startX; x < endX; x++){
    for (int y = startY; y < endY; y++){
        if (pixel.colorDistance(Color.RED) < 167){ // <==== pixel is null !
                    pixel.setColor(newColor);
        }
    }
}
```